# Xclients..how it work?

Tags: x11

I want to test Xclient script
I create it and edit

```
vim $HOME/.Xclients
```

I simply put this line

```
/usr/bin/xeyes
```

Make a startx and...nothing happen.
Script has correct permissions(755) and owned by my user.
System is Slackware 14.2

Comment: What exactly happens? Any X errors? A black screen? A flash of graphics then returned to the console?

Comment: Simply..nothing happen,X start,but no xeyes